# Is it possible to project fields based on the field name in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, data-analysis

In a collection, the documents may contains fields like "name", "name:en", "name:de"

```
{
    _id:123456
    tag:{
        name: HongKong
        name-zh: 香港
        other_tag1: value1
        other_tag2: value2
    }
}
{
    _id:123457
    tag:{
        name-en: Beijing
        other_tag1: value1
        other_tag2: value2
    }
}
```

What I want is to list out all fields with field name contains "name". I tried with the following codes, but it seems to be stupid, and doesn't list all possible "name"s.

```
find = {'$or': [{'tag.name': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name:zh': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name:en': {'$exists': 1}}]}
project = {'_id': 0, 'name': '$tag.name', 'name:zh': '$tag.name:zh', 'name:en': '$tag.name:en'}
names = list(db.node.aggregate([{'$match': find}, {'$project': project}]))
```

And the result I want is:

```
{
    name: HongKong
    name-zh: 香港
}
{
    name-en: Beijing
}
```

Comment: Can you show an expected result?

Comment: It is not possible to have same key in a document. like `name:HongKong` and `name:zh`  Is that right document ?

Comment: @Veeram 'name:zh' is a key in dict. It's confusing. I've changed ':' to '-'.

Comment: All you have to do is correct field names ? Something like `find = {'$or': [{'tag.name': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name-zh': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name-en': {'$exists': 1}}]}
project = {'_id': 0, 'name': '$tag.name', 'name-zh': '$tag.name-zh', 'name-en': '$tag.name-en'}
names = list(db.node.aggregate([{'$match': find}, {'$project': project}]))`

Comment: @Veeram That's right. The query I wrote returns {tag.name, tag.name:en and tag.name:zh} if any of them exists. And I expect to get all fields with "name" in the field name.

Comment: So you would like to return only the matched names in your output not all names correct ? What is your mongo version ?

Comment: @Veeram MongoDB 3.4.9. I want return all fields and values with field name in a specific pattern, and in this case the pattern is "name" or start with "name:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to search field names using `$objectToArray` It may not a optimal solution based on data you need to search.

`$objectToArray` to change the tag into array of key value pair followed by `$unwind` to search the keys for the input pattern and `$group + $arrayToObject` to return the matching key value pairs.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match:{'$or': [{'tag.name': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name-zh': {'$exists': 1}}, {'tag.name-en': {'$exists': 1}}]}}, 
    {$project:{"tagskv":{$objectToArray:"$tag"}}},
    {$unwind:"$tagskv"},
    {$match:{"tagskv.k": { $regex: /name/i }}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", names:{$push:"$tagskv"}}},
    {$project:{"names":{$arrayToObject:"$names"}}},
    {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$names"}}
])
```